# Can we find two sequences $(a_{n}),(b_{n})$ with several conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can we find two sequences $(a_{n}),(b_{n})$ such that
$$a_{n}>b_{n}>0 \\ \lim_{n→∞}a_{n}=\lim_{n→∞}b_{n}=0 \\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n^{-n}}{a_{n+1}^{-n-1}}<1<\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_n^{-n}}{b_{n+1}^{-n-1}}$$

I thought on the the cases $a_{n}=a⁻ⁿ$ and $b_{n}=b⁻ⁿ$ for some fixed $a$ and $ b$ but there is a contradiction for these cases.

Comment: That depends; can you edit your post first and explain what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. Let $b_n$ be a positive sequence going to zero. Then for infinitely many $n$, $b_{n+1} < b_n < 1$, hence $(b_{n+1})^{n+1} < (b_n)^n$ so $\displaystyle \frac{(b_n)^{-n}}{(b_{n+1})^{-(n+1)}} < 1$.